# Powershell - how to show which computers from a list are running a specific process?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-7, powershell-4.0

Powershell beginner here working in an air-gapped, Win7 environment with Powershell 4.0 so unable to import any modules or do anything sophisticated but wondering how I can achieve generating a txt file of computers on the network that are running a specific process, say wusa.exe for Windows Updates?

I have a txt list of all the computer names already and so far have this:

```
$computers = gc "C:\PCList.txt"
foreach ($computer in $computers) {Get-process | out-file -Path "C:\TheseAreRunningWusa.txt"}
```

But obviously that displays ALL processes, any way to cut out everything aside from a specific one but also only list the ones running said process?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Get-Process command allows you to specify both a remote computer to run on, and what service you are looking for.

```bsh
$computers = Get-Content "C:\PCList.txt"
$output = @()

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
  if(Get-Process "myProcessName" -ComputerName $computer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
    $output += $computer
  }
}
$output | Set-Content "C:\TheseAreRunningMyProcess.txt"
```

Note: I used `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` as `Get-Process` throws an error if the process is not found.

Comment: Makes more sense, knew there was an IF statement needed somewhere. Will give it a shot, thank you!